# Font dialog test area

Tags: java, fonts, javafx

I am trying to make a font dialog with a testing area. My problem is that when I test really big fonts, the window expands to huge sizes. Is there a way I can make the parent of the `Label` be not effected by the label size?

Here is my FXML code:

```
<center>
    <ScrollPane hbarPolicy="NEVER" vbarPolicy="NEVER">
        <Label fx:id="testFontLabel" text="%fontselector.test"/>
    </ScrollPane>
</center>
```

When I set `testFontLabel` font to size 60 before the `Stage` is shown, and then show it, I get this:

[image]

Obviously, I don't want this huge demo area, I would like the text to be cut off underneath the rest of the content. I tried setting the `ScrollPane`'s max size, but that causes undesirable effects because resizes to the `Stage` do not resize the `ScrollPane`

Comment: Nobody has any ideas? I thought this would have been something easy to solve :/

Answer (score 0):

Got it! I just had to set the preferred width of the `ScrollPane`.